# invalid syntax указывает на скобочку

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Вот сайт:http://vnc.miks-it.ru:81/ мне нужно парсить каждую строку, я написал такой код, выдает ошибку. В чем моя ошибка?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('http://vnc.miks-it.ru:81')

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

for tr2 in soup.select('body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)')

print(tr2.text)
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Внимательно изучите синтаксис for

Answer (score 2):

Строка с `for ... in ...` обязательно должна заканчиваться двоеточием.

А тело цикла (в вашем случае это одна следующая строчка) обязательно должно идти с отступом.